# 2 different IP addresses are contradicting

Tags: proxy, ip

When I login to this site: http://forum.supercell.net/mobile.php?do=login 5times with wrong password their "warning" email shows my correct public IP as shown in comment box but when I do this same thing again with "onavo extend" app running this time their "warning" email displays an "internal IP" as shown in comment box . I'm wondering from where they are taking internal IP? It only happens when I use "onavo extend" which is data compressing android app. I think it has to do with the proxy server of onavo extend which might be providing me an internal IP but I don't know exactly. Can anyone explain it?

"My question is related with proxy and that hidden internal IP address it is showing." The website and the app I mentioned in this question are used just for reference to give more detail so it shouldn't be treated as off-topic.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/whNf2.jpg http://i.stack.imgur.com/GWO0x.jpg One more thing, the internal IP you are watching in the picture is not provided by my ISP. I checked it. ISP given internal IP is different.

Answer (score 2):

> **I think it has to do with the proxy server of onavo extend which might be providing me an internal IP but I don't know exactly.**

Yes, "Onavo extend" uses Onavo's servers to compress your data. The web-server serving the content presumably sees the Onavo server as the client.

An ordinary proxy server inserts HTTP headers such as [Forwarded-For](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For).

> Forwarded: for=192.0.2.60; proto=http; by=203.0.113.43

Since the 10.33.176.124 shown in your screen captures is an unrouteable address in the [RFC1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) "private address" ranges. This would normally be hidden using a router that uses network address translation (NAT) to substitute it's external IP-address for the internal private address. I guess the web-server *might* be obtaining this information from a proxy HTTP header like this.

If you run a public facing HTTP server, you can probably check this by accessing it using a smartphone with Onavo extend enabled and then checking the HTTP-server logs or using a sniffer (tcpdump, wireshark, whatever).

Comment: Don't you think X-Forwarded-For should be equal to my public IP instead of that internal IP assigned by onavo proxy servers? Do proxy servers even assign any internal IP because they are only "middle-men"? What I know is that proxy servers use your public IP to connect with and inject XFF to let destination server know which is the source. I don't think Internal IP and NAT have to be involved in it.

Comment: X-Forwarded-For is typically the IP address of the client requesting access through a proxy. This can be useful for load balancing purposes for upstream devices but can sometimes cause issues on websites that use the Header for geolocation purposes.

Comment: Does proxy server also assign internal IP if they use XFF?